# AltoRouter POST Data

Tags: php, altorouter

I tried to work with AltoRouter to send a contact form, but I get no POST content.

this are my routes:

```
$router->map('GET','/kontakt/', 'views/kontakt.php', 'kontakt');
$router->map('POST','/sendContact/', 'views/sendContact.php', 'sendContact');

$match = $router->match();

if($match) {
  require $match['target'];
}
else {
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

this is my form contact form

```
<form name="contactForm" action="./sendContact/" method="post">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputVorname">Vorname</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputVorname" placeholder="Vorname">
        </div>
</form>
```

this is sendContact.php

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);
```

But the output is

> array(0) { }

What must I do to catch the POST Data to work with them?

Thanks

Comment: It's working just fine.  You didn't put a name field in the `<input>` so the name will be 0....and if you don't fill something in you get `{}`

Comment: lol. thanks so much, to much trees in the forrest :D